# How to get the beta value for a subgroup interaction effect out of lmer?

Tags: r, regression, lme4-nlme, interaction

I am doing a subgroup analysis using interactions rather than stratifying in order to get more statistical power.  We have males and females in 3 racial identities.  We are predicting cortical thickness (the grey matter in the brain) for specific regions.  My supervisor wants me to make a heatmap of the beta's of each predictor and I'm just trying to wrap my head around how to calculate them accurately.  I have provided a stripped down lmer formula here.

```
#Example design
fml.test <-lmer(temp[,307]~1+(1|mri_info_deviceserialnumber)+  #this models random effect for site
                  (1|mri_info_deviceserialnumber:rel_family_id)+#this  models random effect by nesting family
                  interview_age+rel_relationship+ehi_y_ss_scoreb+
                  scale(smri_vol_scs_intracranialv)+
                  sex+ race_ethnicity+
                  trauma+ #terms of interest start here
                  sex:trauma + 
                  race_ethnicity:trauma + sex:race_ethnicity:trauma,
                data = temp)
```

So in reality I have 45 other variables of interest including trauma.  The fixed effects are reported here...

```
> betas.fixed = coef(summary(fml.test))
> betas.fixed
                                       Estimate Std. Error        df       t value   Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                       1615.51041341   5.433032  280.3825 297.349716346 0.00000000
interview_age                       -3.98750912   2.053376 8898.7656  -1.941928806 0.05217724
rel_relationship1                   -1.42476717   5.802770 8518.9982  -0.245532242 0.80605026
rel_relationship2                   -2.90665343   6.087463  162.7454  -0.477481898 0.63365964
rel_relationship3                  -74.20411436  39.676183 9065.7667  -1.870243278 0.06148224
ehi_y_ss_scoreb2                    -0.03876993   7.924189 9069.9698  -0.004892605 0.99609639
ehi_y_ss_scoreb3                    -3.06035258   6.075014 9067.2651  -0.503760560 0.61444188
scale(smri_vol_scs_intracranialv)  130.20210178   2.033029 9073.4266  64.043417954 0.00000000
sexM                                 2.32397492   6.391389 9073.8071   0.363610293 0.71615751
race_ethnicity2                      7.90152112  10.463006 7103.0702   0.755186509 0.45016212
race_ethnicity3                     -1.52549699   8.968859 2714.6488  -0.170088182 0.86495346
trauma1                              3.62891223   8.240146 9071.6447   0.440394191 0.65966212
sexM:trauma1                        -0.77588532  11.310149 9070.0397  -0.068600801 0.94530889
race_ethnicity2:trauma1            -15.54702696  16.499700 9071.5480  -0.942261218 0.34608401
race_ethnicity3:trauma1             14.49093249  15.163044 9072.3241   0.955674398 0.33926222
sexM:race_ethnicity2:trauma0         8.75004347  14.494035 9070.0173   0.603699610 0.54605847
sexM:race_ethnicity3:trauma0         3.55070519  12.001929 9067.7164   0.295844544 0.76735558
sexM:race_ethnicity2:trauma1       -10.37258299  18.062565 9072.3727  -0.574258584 0.56580707
sexM:race_ethnicity3:trauma1       -12.20972991  17.373213 9071.1353  -0.702790566 0.48220431
```

Being female is the reference level for sex and the reference level for race_ethnicity is race_ethnicity1.  So if I want to calculate the beta for the effect of trauma in females in race_ethnicity3 I want...$$\hat \beta_0 + \hat \beta_{ethnicity3} + \hat \beta_{trauma} + \hat \beta_{ethnicity3:trauma}$$

```
> rownames(betas.fixed)[c(1,11,12,15)]
[1] "(Intercept)"             "race_ethnicity3"         "trauma1"                 "race_ethnicity3:trauma1"
>  beta.sexF.eth3 = betas.fixed[1,1] + betas.fixed[11,1] + 
+     betas.fixed[12,1] + betas.fixed[15,1]
> beta.sexF.eth3
[1] 1632.105
```

But since I am interested if the effect is positive or negative I would report it as...

```
>  beta.sexF.eth3 = betas.fixed[11,1] + 
+     betas.fixed[12,1] + betas.fixed[15,1]
> beta.sexF.eth3
[1] 16.59435
```

Is this correct?  For males I would want to include the seM:trauma interaction and the sexM:ethnicity3 interaction term as well right?  And the effects of trauma is for females in race_ethnicity 1 correct?

Comment: By "beta value for a subgroup interaction effect", do you mean you want to know how an individual of specified sex, ethnicity, and trauma is predicted to differ from the intercept? If so it might be easier to make a new data set of the groups you're interested in and hand that to the newdata argument of predict.

Comment: @DAWells doing that loses statistical power and is not recommended.  Your confidence intervals estimated by using a smaller sample size will be wider, but not because the variance of your predictor is you've just used a smaller sample size than you've needed to.

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/419580/conducting-a-subgroup-analysis-with-regression-modeling

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean retrain the model, I meant make predictions for your existing model but just for hypothetical cases you're interested in. I think it's an easier way to get the same answer you described if you plan to do it for lots of cases. As long as you handle the random effects carefully.